# JSONDecoder - Execute method for each element decoded

Tags: arrays, swift, decodable, jsondecoder

I am using JSONDecoder to decode JSON to an array of MyModel :

```
myModelArray : [MyModel] = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyModel].self, from: data)
```

Everything is working fine, I get my array, but I want to execute a method for each element of my model array each time the element finished to be decoded. 
Right now I am doing this :

```
for city in myModelArray! {
    //Creating polygon 
    city.createPolygon()
}
```

It works but it is not optimal, is there a way to execute a method each time the Decoder finished to decode one element of the array ? Like a completition for example ?

Thanks

Comment: What about manually decoding `MyModel` by overriding `init(from decoder: Decoder)`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joakim answer, I just had to decode manually by overriding **init(from decoder: Decoder)** in my Decodable model like this :

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    property1 = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .property1)
    property2 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .property2)

    //Calling my method
    getCityPolygon()
}
```